# Conditionally add to array of objects using spread operator

Tags: javascript

I would like to conditionally add something to an array using a spread operator if it matches a particular condition (ie. if the movie id does not match other movie id's that already exist in my array)

```
case ADD_FAVORITE:
    return {
            ...state,
            favorites: [ state.favorites !== action.payload.id? ...state.favorites, action.payload]
    }
```

This is what I have tried

action payload returns something like this

```
{id: 0, title: 'The Godfather', director: 'Francis Ford Coppola', metascore: 100, genre: 'Drama', …}
```

and inside state.favorites:

```
description: "Luke Skywalker joins forces with a Jedi Knight, a cocky pilot, a Wookiee and two droids to save the galaxy from the Empire's world-destroying battle station, while also attempting to rescue Princess Leia from the mysterious Darth Vader."
director: "George Lucas"
genre: "Scifi"
id: 1
metascore: 92
title: "Star Wars"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to end up with? is `favorites` an array or an object?

Comment: <pedantry>`...` isn't an operator. Operators can't do what rest and spread syntax do.</pedantry> :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd do the check before the `return`, since you don't need to update `state` at all if nothing changes:

```
case ADD_FAVORITE:
    if (state.favorites.some(({id}) => id === action.payload.id)) {
        // It's already there, we don't need to modify state at all
        return state;
    }
    return {...state, favorites: [...state.favorites, action.payload]};
```

---

If you *want* to update state even though nothing changes, just do that in the branch:

```
case ADD_FAVORITE:
    if (state.favorites.some(({id}) => id === action.payload.id)) {
        // It's already there, we don't need to modify state at all
        return {...state};
    }
    return {...state, favorites: [...state.favorites, action.payload]};
```

or

```
case ADD_FAVORITE:
    let favorites = state.favorites;
    if (!favorites.some(({id}) => id === action.payload.id)) {
        // Don't have it, add it
        favorites = [...favorites, action.payload];
    }
    return {...state, favorites};
```

(Again, *if* you want to return a new state object even when nothing changes.)